# Play randomized <video> on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `<video>` tag with 3 sources and would like to randomize them and select one when my website loads:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="video_mainhub" style="width: 100%;height: auto;position:absolute;z-index: -1">
  <source src="./video/vid95.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="./video/vid70.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="./video/vid65.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What issue are you having with writing this logic yourself?  You are expected to make an attempt, not just ask others to write code for you.  [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I can do this for $50 lol

Answer (score 0):

For someone with the same problem, here's the solution:

```
<video src="./video/vid95.mp4" autoplay muted loop id="video_mainhub"></video>
```

and javascript:

```
var vidElement = document.getElementById('video_mainhub');
var vidSources = [
  "./video/vid95.mp4", 
  "./video/vid70.mp4",
  ];
var activeVideo = Math.floor((Math.random() * vidSources.length));
vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
vidElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % vidSources.length;
  if(activeVideo === vidSources.length){
    activeVideo = 0;
  }

  // update the video source and play
  vidElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
  vidElement.play();
});
```